# Dropping column with quotation marks in column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I added a column using following commands (I used quotation marks so that N is in upper case in my column name)

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
  ADD “Name” VARCHAR(50);
```

However, I see "nam" column in my table now after running that command.

How can I drop that column?

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
  DROP COLUMN "Name";
```

I get following error:

> ERROR: column "name" of relation "new_table" does not exist

The following statement causes this error:

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
DROP COLUMN "Name";
```

Comment: I would move all the data in the table to a temporary table then `DROP` the table and recreate it, then move the data back.

Answer (score 1):

seems you are not using  double quote `"`  in first query bus some others quotes try suing the same chars `“”`

```
ALTER TABLE new_table DROP COLUMN “Name”;
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b50ace321c0a4629d2b308acb6915852

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see the edit section in my answer, hope things are clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Check how Postgres is storing the column name when you are using a double quote in column name:

```
select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where 
table_name='tab1';
```

Also, you may view the same when you execute a select statement:

```
select * from table;
```

Copy the same column name text in your alter statement. Here is the sample column name with both kind of double quotes in PostgreSQL:

```
create table tab1(data varchar(30));

alter table tab1 ADD “Name1” varchar(50);
alter table tab1 ADD "Name2" varchar(50);

select *from tab1;
select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='tab1';

alter table tab1 drop column “Name1”;
alter table tab1 drop column "Name2";


table_name  column_name
tab1        data
tab1        “name1”
tab1        Name2
```

Here is the link to the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=69b51311a11d9c856617d3cb0f563824)

Note: Avoid using a double quote in the table name, column, etc. In case you use you have to ensure that the same names are specified in all queries.

**Edit:**

It's simple. If you use `"Name"` (not same as `“Name”`, notice quote angle) in the column name then you have to refer the column as `"Name"`. In case `“Name”` is used then you have to refer by `“Name”`. The quotes need to match.

Another observation is when `"Name"` used as column name it makes the column name as `Name` (N uppercase) as opposed to all lowercase column names by default in the database but needs to be referred as `"Name"`.

Comment: See the edit section in the answer, hope things are clear now :)

Comment: Run it yourself in live PostgreSQL database and experience: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=69b51311a11d9c856617d3cb0f563824.